# How an 'if (A && B)' statement is evaluated?

Tags: c++

```
if( (A) && (B) )
{
  //do something
}
else
  //do something else
```

The question is, would the statement immediately break to else if A was FALSE.  Would B even get evaluated?

I ask this in the case that B checking the validity of an array index say array[0] when the array is actually empty and has zero elements.  Therefore throwing a segfault because we are trying to access something that is out of bounds of the array.  Specifically

```
if( (array.GetElements() > 0) && (array[0]))
  array[0]->doSomething();
else
  //do nothing and return
```

This may be dangerous if array[0] actually gets evaluated because it segfaults without the first check to the left of the '&&'.  Precedence tells me that the left side will definitely take precedence but it doesn't tell me that it won't evaluate the right side if the left is FALSE.

Comment: The other canonical form is `if (p && p->bar) {  }`. This is also safe.

Comment: If you just want to "do nothing and return", you should leave off the "else" entirely. Otherwise, the compiler will either complain that there is no statement to go with the else (if the else is the last thing in the enclosing block) or, worse, take the next statement and use that as the statement to put in the else block.

Comment: I tried to use the comments as a placeholder that means: some code will go here, but it's not important enough to include in my example. The reality of the situation is that there is code that returns in the else's scope but also code after the else's scope.  Hopefully that clears it up

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In C and C++, the `&&` and `||` operators "short-circuit". That means that they only evaluate a parameter if required. If the first parameter to `&&` is false, or the first to `||` is true, the rest will not be evaluated.

The code you posted is safe, though I question why you'd include an empty `else` block.

Comment: Yes my comment was incorrect, changed to //do nothing and return which is more accurate in this case.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you overload operator && or || in your own class, they do NOT short-circuit anymore.  Something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Kristo, I did not know that!  However, I don't think there are any sane cases to overload that operator.  Overloading the bool cast operator would be more useful I think.

Comment: @Kristo » That's to be expected, right? The compiler can't always be sure if your special overload of && will cause side effects, so to be safe it evaluates both operands.

Answer (score 12):

You are asking about the `&&` operator, not the `if` statement.

`&&` [short-circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), meaning that if while working it meets a condition which results in only one answer, it will stop working and use that answer.

So, `0 && x` will execute `0`, then terminate because there is no way for the expression to evaluate non-zero regardless of what is the second parameter to `&&`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is called [Short-circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

If the validity of the boolean statement can be assured after part of the statement, the rest is not evaluated.

This is very important when some of the statements have side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

For the case where A and B are both integers, floating point types, or pointers:

### What does `while (a && b)` do when `a` and `b` are both integers, floating point types, or pointers?

AKA: rules of `int`egers or other numbers being cast to `bool`s.

### Short answer

When `a` and `b` are both integers, floating point types, or pointers, writing `while (a && b)` is equivalent to `while ((bool)a && (bool)b)`, and whenever you cast an one of these types to a `bool`, *zero is `false` and everything else is `true`.*

If `(bool)a` is false (value zero), then it stops evaluating early, since certainly `a && b` cannot be true if the first part of that test is false.

### When does "contextual conversion to bool" apply?

This concept applies to `if`, `for`, `while`, and `do { } while` blocks, not just `while`. It applies to `!`, `||`, and `&&` operators. The operands in such expressions are "said to be *contextually converted to bool*".

See here:

1. [@MSalters' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331318/how-an-if-a-b-statement-is-evaluated/74407605?noredirect=1#comment131356112_74407605). Thank you.
2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion and search for "contextually converted to bool". This source says that the "contextual conversion to bool" occurs for all of the following situations:

   1. the controlling expression of `if`, `while`, `for`
   2. the operands of the built-in logical operators `!`, `&&` and `||`
   3. the first operand of the conditional [ternary] operator `? :`
   4. the predicate in a `static_assert()` declaration
   5. the expression in a `noexcept` specifier
   6. the expression in an `explicit` specifier (since C++20)

### Details

`while (a && b)` is exactly equivalent to `while ((bool)a == true && (bool)b == true)`, which is also exactly equivalent to `while (a != 0 && b != 0)` or (same thing): `while (a != false && b != false)`.

Those can be read as: "while integers, floating point types, or pointers a and b are both true when cast to bool", or as: "while integers, floating point types, or pointers a and b are both non-zero."

I think most people prefer the `while (a && b)` form, however, since it's the shortest and still easy to read.

The key takeaway is:

These all mean and do the same thing:

```cpp
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
// // or
// float a = 2.0;
// float b = 3.0;
// // or 
// int* a = (int*)0x11223344UL;
// int* b = (int*)0xaabbccddUL;
// // etc.

// these are all **equivalent**!:

// 1. "true"-based forms
while (a && b) {};              // shortest and most-often used version
while ((bool)a && (bool)b) {};  // most-explicit and clear version
while ((bool)a == true && (bool)b == true) {};
while (((bool)a == true) && ((bool)b == true)) {};

// 2. "false"-based forms (these all are exactly equivalent to the "true"-based
// forms above)
while (a != 0 && b != 0) {};
while ((a != 0) && (b != 0)) {};
while (a != false && b != false) {};

// etc.
```

The following, however, are NOT the same as the examples above:

```cpp
while (a == true && b == true) {};
while ((a == true) && (b == true)) {};
```

This is because `true` is defined strictly as `1` (and `false` is defined strictly as `0`). *Therefore, even though `a == 1` is **false** when `a` is `2`, `(bool)a == 1` is **true** when `a` is *any non-zero integer*, including `2`.*

<sub>Note: this answer has been completely rewritten and fixed for correctness, and moved to here from this now-deleted question here: [What does `while (a && b)` do when `a` and `b` are both integers? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73683952/4561887). That question was deleted under the premise it was a duplicate of this question, hence why I moved my answer to here.</sub>

Comment: It might benefit from some generalization: it works for `if`, `for`, `while` and `do { ] while`, and for integral types, FP types and pointers too. This is called _contextually converted to bool_.

Comment: @MSalters, done. Thank you. I wasn't aware of that term but it gave me something to google. It also wasn't clear to me to what extent this concept applied, so than you for clarifying it applies to integers, floating point types, and pointers too.

Answer (score -1):

for logical && both the parameters must be true ,
then it ll be entered in if {} clock otherwise it ll execute else {}.
for logical || one of parameter or condition is true is sufficient to execute if {}.

```
if( (A) && (B) ){
     //if A and B both are true
}else{
}
if( (A) ||(B) ){
     //if A or B is true 
}else{
}
```

Comment: That's not what the question is asking about.

Answer (score -1):

i will try to clear it as much as possible consider this below example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int a= 1;
  int b = 0;
  if(a && b++)
  printf("%d  %d",a++,b);
  
  printf("%d  %d",a,b);
}
```

Output 1 1

**now the same code with a = 0;**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int a= 0;
  int b = 0;
  if(a && b++)
  printf("%d  %d",a++,b);
  
  printf("%d  %d",a,b);
}
```

Output : 0 0

as you can clearly see inside a if condition with &&(and) operation if the first argument is 0 then no matter what the value of b is this condition will fail so the second operator b wont even get executed.

**with that being said if instead of && we kept ||(OR) then the result would be diff**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int a= 0;
  int b = 0;
  if(a || b++)
  printf("%d  %d",a++,b);
  
  printf("%d  %d",a,b);
}
```

Output: 0  1

because now even though a was 0 there is still a chance be could be 1 and thus the compiler executes the line.

Comment: `void main()` is not valid standard C++. The return type of `main` _must_ be `int`.

Comment: @user17732522 it's just for demo purpose to explain the workings

Comment: Showing what does happen in one scenario is not good evidence of what must happen in all scenarios.

Answer (score -2):

**Even in python short circuiting happens**

```py
a = []
if 0 and a[0]:  # short circuit happens
    print("short circuit")
if 1 and a[0]:  # we get IndexError: list index out of range exception
    print("this will not be evaluated")
```

Comment: This question is not about Python. It is also not clear what "even" is supposed to imply here.

Answer (score -6):

yes, if( (A) && (B) ) will fail on the first clause, if (A) evaluates false.

this applies to any language btw, not just C derivatives. For threaded and parallel processing this is a different story ;)

Comment: Not every language. Some languages, such as Visual Basic, have logical operators which do *not* short circuit.

Comment: I would like to point out that this has not been the case with VB for a long time, before the "OrElse" and "AndAlso" were introduce. Even now, the "Or" and "And" do not short circuit. The reason for this is that previously the logical and bitwise "Or" and  "And" operators were the same.

Comment: Some languages, such as Ada, have both options available ("AND"/"AND THEN" and "OR"/"OR ELSE").

Comment: That means that VB is brain-damaged (go figure). Are we trying to appease the R->L language people by not caring about this?

Comment: In fact, `C++` also has non-short-circuiting boolean operators - `&` and `|`. So long as you apply them to `bool` values and not integers.

Comment: @xcramps - short circuit booleans are convenient most of the time, but they are a language design CHOICE. There is nothing that makes them inherently a better choice in every situation. Pretending they are the only way to do things is silly and misleading. They are just the most common way to do things.

Comment: & and | and how they apply to short-circuit operators is an issue of logical precedence though, isn't it Pavel?

Comment: @crotch, & and | do not short-circuit in C++, regardless of where they are used, unless they are overloaded (if that is possible), in which case I don't know what happens.  Remember that & is not &&, and | is not ||.

Comment: You can overload `&` in general, but it's predefined (and thus not overloadable) for `bool`s. Technically it's still defined as bitwise OR, but since `bool`s in C++ are specifically defined as integral type where `false==0` and `true==1` (and no other value is meaningful), bitwise OR on them is effectively non-short-circuiting logical OR.

Comment: @strager: C++ evaluates all operands before calling a function, even if that function is named "operator&&". Hence such overloads do not short-circuit.