# Is it safe to make shortcut if statements

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a flash card project and I need to check the first line of a file to make sure it is the right type, but using the same function on other lines will ask a question. I know in some compilers this will work, but I'm not sure about all. Example:

```
if(line == 1 && execLine(line));
```

Is it safe to assume that if line is NOT 1 that it won't even try execLine?

Comment: Same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331318/how-an-if-a-b-statement-is-evaluated)

Comment: No, it's not safe to **assume** that. It is safe to **know** that, because it's what the language definition requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of operator overloading, it is safe to assume that if line is NOT 1 that execLine won't be evaluated.

The `if()` is redundant, though. `line == 1 && execLine(line)` is sufficient.

Comment: Assuming also that execLine doesn't return e.g. void.

Comment: the `if()` is important, as execLine returns true or false if the line executed successfully. The code I showed above is out of context.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You are right, if execLine returns void, even `line==1` is not evaluated, because the code won't compile.

Comment: @applns: then you should update your question to show that.  It drastically changes this from (somewhat) non-idiomatic C to a completely standard idiom.

Comment: How would you even overload an operator?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in infix boolean operators, `&&` and `||`, have guaranteed short-circuit behavior, but user-defined operator overloads don't.

So assuming the `execLine` returns a `bool`, and not some type for which there exists a user-defined overload of `&&`, the behavior of

```
if( line == 1 && execLine( line ) );
```

… is guaranteed.

---

The statement is ungood in several ways, so let's dissect it.

First, a control statement with an empty inner statement is best expressed with a curly braces block containing a single semicolon, because that signals *visually* that it's empty:

```
if( line == 1 && execLine( line ) ) {;}
```

But the `if` is entirely superfluous here, so better:

```
line == 1 && execLine( line );
```

From here we can proceed in two different directions. If we wanted to keep this form we'd address the possible and not unlikely silly-warnings emanating from the compiler, by suppressing them with a cast to `void`, which is the main purpose of this special cast: to tell the compiler that one is intentionally discarding a result value.

```
(void)( line == 1 && execLine( line ) );
```

But instead one should realize that this is just an `if` in disguise. It's not the original `if`, but this `if`:

```
if( line == 1 ) { execLine( line ); }
```