# Conditional if statement bug

Tags: c++

For an assignment in my C++ programming class, we're supposed to create a program that will ask for order information for a product to be shipped, such as price, if it's fragile, the designated country, etc. Everything else except for one little if statement doesnt work correctly, and it's the one that prints out an error message if when typing in the country, it's not one of the three listed, no matter what I type, it always spits out the error!

```
if(shippingDestination!="AUS" || shippingDestination != "CAN" || shippingDestination != "USA")
   {
       cout<<"\nWrong destination ! Exiting........."<<endl;
       system("pause");
       exit(0);
   }
```

(And yes, prior to this statement, the input by the user is forced into uppercase, and I have tested this without the statement above, everything works as intended)
I've tried several different variations to this conditional statement to try and get a favorable result, but no matter what I do, it always, always spits out the error.

Comment: Your condition is always true, use `&&` instead

Comment: `shippingDestination` is, at most, only equal to one string and not equal to the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your logical operators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string shippingDestination="";
  cout<< " Enter Destination ";
  cin>>shippingDestination;
  if(shippingDestination!="AUS" && shippingDestination!="CAN" && shippingDestination!="USA" ){
      cout<< "Wrong Destination";
   }else{
      cout<< "Correct Destination";
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "||"! What you want is: &&.

```
if (shippingDestination != "USA" && shippingDestination != "CAN" && shippingDestination != "AUS") {
    cerr << "Wrong desitnation. << endl;
    return 1; // It's convention to return 1 when there is an error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the or operator `||` in the if statement then if any of those conditions are true then whatever is inside the if condition is executed. What you need is the and operator `&&` for this operator all the conditions have to be true. Also I found this answer pretty interesting 
[How an 'if (A && B)' statement is evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331318/how-an-if-a-b-statement-is-evaluated)